# How can I create development and production Cloudfront key pairs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, key-pair

I'm working on a system that uses Amazon S3 to store sensitive user media, which users access via a Cloudfront distribution. I'm locking down public access using [Cloudfront's query parameter authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) so that we create a secure string using a Cloudfront private key. This auth string can be attached to a Cloudfront URL to allow access only to appropriate S3 resources.

However, I'm a little confused on the best way to distribute this private key amongst my team for development. Usually we would have a secret production key that only works for our production distribution and a less secret development key that works on our staging distributions.

However, the Cloudfront docs indicate that keypairs [can only be created by the root AWS user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tasks-that-require-root.html), who is allowed a maximum of 2 keys (for key rotation purposes). At the same time, the docs indicate that you can [specify different accounts as trusted signers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html) and limit them to specific distributions. If this is true, I believe I could lock down specific distributions to keys created by specific users.

Can anyone help me understand:

1. if the root user is actually the only user that can create cloudfront key pairs? (Maybe through [Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/), I can create other non-IAM, root-like users?)
2. how we might create a development key pair that only allows access to our development distributions?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

1. I [created another non-IAM account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_create.html) in my Organization from the primary root user.
2. From there, I logged into this account to generate and download a new Cloudfront keypair.
3. To ensure this new keypair could only be used with the Cloudfront distribution(s) I wanted, I did the following for each of my distributions:

   1. Visited the **Behaviors tab** > Edit
   2. Checked **Specify Accounts** under Trusted Signers
   3. Entered only the account number of the root user I wanted to allow access for into **AWS Account Numbers**"

I hope this clears up the process for someone else!

Comment: This is not recommended approach, due to the fact that you need to create key pair id using root account. Recommended approach is to use trusted groups instead.